# How-to call for external XML data within an AngularJS directive?

Tags: xml, angularjs

I can not for the life of me string together the right set of factories, controllers and directives to get this to work. Seems as if it should be simple...

Given some html:

```
<productcard product="12345"></productcard>
```

I'd like AngularJS to grab the xml for that product, fill in the template, and plop the new HTML on the page.

http://plnkr.co/edit/k8fpHbliYTGUv78YcDYI?p=preview

```
.factory('prodDetails', function($resource) {
   return $resource(':id', { id: '@productId' }, { responseType: "xml" });
})
.controller('prodDetailsCtrl', function($scope, prodDetails){
  //prodDetails.get({productId: 35990});
  //console.log("blah");
})
.directive('productcard', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      productId: "@"
    },
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      //$scope.blah = prodDetails.query({magId : 12345});
      //prodDetails.get({productId: 35990})
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '{{productId}}'
  };
});
```

I'm really new to Angular and am at a complete loss. I've been through the docs every which way, done the demos and read 100s of posts here on SO. I'm clearly not getting something.

Thanks for any guidance you might provide.

Comment: _How-to call for external JSON_ vs. _I'd like AngularJS to grab the xml_ Is it XML or JSON? And what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: directive scope is expecting attribute `product-id` but markup is `product`

Comment: Oops. I thought it was JSON. It's actually XML. I can't quite get to that part, though. I have the factory and controller set up, but I'm getting an error ($injector:unpr) that I don't understand and it's stopping me from even experimenting with the returned data.

Comment: @charlietfl I don't see this error anywhere...I'd love if this were just a typo!

Comment: `productId: "@"` implies attribute `product-id`, markup is `product="1234"`

Comment: You can also inject services into your directive just as you did for your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $injector error is due to ngResource being in a separate file that you need to include as a reference (ng-resource.js) and also specify as a dependency in the module declaration: `angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', ['ngResource'])`.

The working code is as follows, where the return value of the `prodDetails` factory is hardcoded, since a url wasn't specified.

```
.factory('prodDetails', function() {
   //return $resource(':id', { id: '@productId' }, { responseType: "xml" });
   return { 
     get: function (obj) {
       return {
        id: obj.productId,
        name: 'Awesome Product',
        desc: 'A very awesome product'
       };
     }
   };
})
.directive('productcard', function (prodDetails) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      productId: '@'
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
      var x = prodDetails.get({ productId: scope.productId});
      element.html('<strong>' + x.id + ', ' + x.name + '</strong>');
    }
  };
});
```